# 1990s-2000s SYFY channel movie where a team infiltrate a mansion to shut down a lab

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

All I remember is a group of mercenaries are hired by a man to infiltrate a mansion. Each mercenary has their own talents (leader, explosive expert, big guy, hacker and a chick). They go in and are killed one by one by stuff in the mansion. Eventually there are 3 left. They pursued by this robot and the big muscular guy stays behind to fight the robot. The other two find themselves in a lab I think and they are trying to shut something down? Sounds like *Resident Evil* I know, but its not. There are no zombies in this film.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/DeathMachine comes to mind, but it's an office building, and not as much of an organized team.

Comment: It sounds *a lot* like Resident Evil

Comment: How that robot looked like? Android, human-like, or just some killing machine? What was that killing stuff?

Comment: In Nemesis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_(1992_film) there is a lab and fight with the robot, team want to shutdown the lab.

Comment: Sounds like the inverse of [_Leverage_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1103987) except for an explosives guy.